# Pythonic way of writing a library function which accepts multiple types?

Tags: python

If, as a simplified example, I am writing a library to help people model populations I might have a class such as:

```
class Population:
    def __init__(self, t0, initial, growth):
        self.t0 = t0,
        self.initial = initial
        self.growth = growth
```

where t0 is of type datetime. Now I want to provide a method to determine the population at a given time, whether that be a datetime or a float containing the number of seconds since t0. Further, it would be reasonable for the caller to provide an array of such times (if so, I think it reasonable to assume they will all be of the same type). There are at least two ways I can see to accomplish this:

1. Method for each type

   ```
   def at_raw(self, t):
       if not isinstance(t, collections.Iterable):
           t = numpy.array([t])
       return self.initial*numpy.exp(self.growth*t)
   def at_datetime(self, t):
       if not isinstance(t, collections.Iterable):
           t = [t]
       dt = numpy.array([(t1-self.t0).total_seconds() for t1 in t])
       return self.at_raw(dt)
   ```
2. Universal method

   ```
   def at(self, t):
       if isinstance(t, datetime):
           t = (t-self.t0).total_seconds()
       if isinstance(t, collections.Iterable):
           if isinstance(t[0], datetime):
               t = [(t1-self.t0).total_seconds() for t1 in t]
       else:
           t = np.array([t])
       return self.initial*numpy.exp(self.growth*t)
   ```

Either would work, but I'm not sure which is more pythonic. I've seen some suggestions that type checking indicates bad design which would suggest method 1 but as this is a library intended for others to use, method 2 would probably be more useful.

Note that it is necessary to support times given as floats, even if only the library itself uses this feature, for example I might implement a method which root finds for stationary points in a more complicated model where the float representation is clearly preferable. Thanks in advance for any suggestions or advice.

Comment: Not sure if you will get anything better than peoples opinions for a question like this.  The most important thing is that whatever you choose is well documented and preferably doesn't change in future versions.  Personally I think the second is better.

Comment: Read PEP 443 and then re-implement it in your version of Python. It's coming in Python 3.4.

Comment: I would think that offering the user some type flexibility is quite different from the arguably poor code smell where you inspect the type of your own data.

Comment: A "Pythonic" way to avoid type-checking (which you're doing in both methods, btw) is to use `try/except` with the likely cases attempted first.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments, very helpful. Agreed about the importance of documentation and concreteness - hence my careful consideration of a small issue. I think I'll use 'Method 2' since that's what I'd like to use if I were to use the library myself. I'm going to use something similar to Abhijit's answer since it makes sense to try/catch rather than check/do. Having a universal method should also make it easier to transition to PEP443 when it becomes commonplace. Thanks again!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you can simply stick with the Python's Duck Typing Philosophy here

```
def at(self, t):
    def get_arr(t):
        try: # Iterate over me
            return [get_arr(t1)[0] for t1 in t]
        except TypeError:
            #Opps am not Iterable
            pass
        try: # you can subtract datetime object
            return [(t-self.t0).total_seconds()]
        except TypeError:
            #Opps am not a datetime object
            pass
        # I am just a float
        return [t]
    self.initial*numpy.exp(self.growth*np.array(get_arr(t)))
```

Its important, how you order the cases

1. Specific Cases should precede generic cases.

   ```
   def foo(num):
       """Convert a string implementation to
          Python Object"""
       try: #First check if its an Integer
           return int(num)
       except ValueError:
           #Well not an Integer
           pass
       try: #Check if its a float
           return float(num)
       except ValueError:
           pass
       #Invalid Number
       raise TypeError("Invalid Number Specified")
   ```
2. Default Case should be the terminating case
3. If successive cases, are mutually exclusive, order them by likeliness.
4. Prepare for the Unexpected by raising Exception. After all `Errors should never pass silently.`